# Why do leukemia and lymphoma cause "night sweats"?

Tags: cancer, human-physiology, pathophysiology

One of the symptoms of these blood cancers is sleep hyperhidrosis (aka night sweats).  Also referred to as [one of the B-symptoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_symptoms), it may be used for prognosis.

**What is the the mechanism behind the symptom?**

> **Possibilities I came up with**:
>
> 1. Body is more likely to be infected due to immune compromise and thus a bacterial or viral etiology
> 2. White cell counts may be very high causing release of cytokines which affect thermal regulation
> 3. Something else

Why is there more sweating at night and not so much in the daytime?

Comment: When the tumor cells infiltrate other tissues and then die, there's a good chance they release some pyrogenic molecules that cause sweating. But, I don't know why at night. Hence, though, it'd be considered a paraneoplastic effect.